# Monitor variable in a loop with VSCode debugger

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, variables, visual-studio-code

I want to monitor values of `num` and `ctrl` while this little code is executing, but I hate blemishing it with `print` statements.
I have tried placing break point at the start of the loop, placing `num` on the watch and then continuing the debug process, but it displayed `num: *not available*`. Placing break point at the end or not placing it at all both resulted in similar outcome.

Placing break point at the if statement resulted in me having to press continue button every time the loop reached the statement, which I deemed implausible.

Any suggestion would be welcome.

```
num = 0
while True:
    num += 1
    ctrl = 0
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            ctrl += 1
    if ctrl == 500:
        print(num)
        break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Log/Trace breakpoints.

- set a normal breakpoint
- right-click the red-dot and select `Edit Breakpoint...`
- in the combo box select `Log Message`
- use `{num}` and `{ctrl}` in the message text

Or

- Place cursor on the line you want the `Log Message`
- Use menu entry `Run` > `New Breakpoint` > `Logpoint...`
- use `{num}` and `{ctrl}` in the message text

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Although I found that printing the variables out works much faster than the debugger log messages. Any Idea why that might be?

Comment: @beardeadclown Who cares, now you don't have to spend time removing this debug stuff, Just `Remove All Breakpoints`. Everything in the debugger runs slower.

Comment: @beardeadclown because when you use a debugger every thing that Python does requires asking the debugger, "what do you want me to do?" Asking constantly makes things slow.

Comment: is there any plugin for that ?

Comment: @AyoubBenayache plugin for what?

Comment: @rioV8 for example an extension to show a program variables with  their realtime values

Comment: @AyoubBenayache Add a `Watch` expression

Comment: This is unbelievably useful! I wanted to see what kind of values I was getting in a loop from an api call and this was a super easy way to do it! :)